# PHPExcel_IOFactory can not identify or load

Tags: php, excel, exception, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel_IOFactory trying to read Excel file.

My php version is PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2

The PHPExcel version is 1.8.0

I can call PHPExcel_IOFactory, but when it loads file on server, it won't respond and it won't throw any exceptions.

I am sure my path (*$temp_dir*) is right. I have tried *xls, xlsx, csv* file with only one cell in inside. None of them works.

```
try {
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007'); // this line works
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($temp_dir); // not work
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($temp_dir);  // not work
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($temp_dir); // not work

}catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($temp_dir,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

I don't know what might be the problem, or is there any way to identify it(I don't know how since I didn't catch any exceptions ?

Comment: Check protections and privileges for the foler; make sure that `$temp_dir` really is a valid file (not simply a folder as the variable name suggests), and a filesystem reference to that file (not a url or relative to the web root)

Comment: And have you checked server logs for errors?

Comment: Thank you! after check the server log I identified the error and solved it. It was `Uncaught Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found `